# Android/XMPP: Unable to reconnect to Server after Connection Type Changes

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I'm currently working on a Project in my University which is an Android-App which is supposed to deliver data to a Server.

In order to do that I require a more or less consistent connection to the server via XMPP. It is not really important that the connection is there 100% of the time, but it because the system is supposed to be more or less invisible to the user, user-interaction is supposed to be minimal.

Both the server and the client are xmpp-clients. I use `jabber.org` as the xmpp server.

I have an Android-Service that is establishing the connection to server and delivers data and this works fine.

Now I tried to make the Service reconnect when connection is lost or is Changed from Wifi to GSM. I wanted to try to make this work with a broadcastreceiver listening to `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`. But I did not even get this far.

This is the problem: I tried running the app and then just disabling my wifi. My Phone than automatically switches to GSM and I lose my connection (which I anticipated). But when I try to reconnect manually (e.g. restarting the service) I get errors from the Server. Also my status is still "available". From that moment on it takes way too long until I can connect again.

```
06-29 18:12:14.888: WARN/System.err(14246): resource-constraint(500)
06-29 18:12:14.890: WARN/System.err(14246):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:110)
06-29 18:12:14.890: WARN/System.err(14246):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:404)
06-29 18:12:14.890: WARN/System.err(14246):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:349)
....
```

I am actually connected to the xmpp Server but it does not deliver my message:

```
06-29 18:12:14.882: INFO/System.out(14246): 06:12:14 nachm. RCV  (1079704816): <iq type='error' id='7rhk4-70'><error code='500' type='wait'><resource-constraint xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>
```

Sometimes I don't get the error, but still no messages are being delivered.

So I think that the server is not allowing me to connect, because I did not disconnect before trying to reconnect. Which I find strange because I thought you could even connect from multiple clients to one account.

I'm posting some code that I think might be relevant:

```
public void connectToServer() throws XMPPException {

    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(
            serverADD, port,
            service);

    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    connection.connect();

    SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);

    connection.login(user_JID,password);

    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            presence.setStatus("available");
            presence.setPriority(24);
    presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
        connection.sendPacket(presence);
}
```

this is how I send the messages:

```
public void sendMessage(String message, String recipient) throws XMPPException {

    chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(recipient, this);
    chat.sendMessage(message);

}
```

Does anyone hava an idea how to solve this? I would even use "dirty" tricks as long as my message gets delivered to the server.

By the way: The senders and the recipients jids are always the same (after initial setup). Just in case anyone thinks that could matter.

Comment: Do you use smack or (a)smack? If (a)smack, which one? If you are reconnecting with the same resource and the server still thinks that there is a valid connection with the same resource, a resource conflict will happen. It's up to the server policy how to handle that.

Comment: I use smack, but by now im confused which one. I used asmack and had problems and then somebody in the internet had a tutorial to patch a smack-version. And I followed this blindly because ist wanted to get rid of that error (don't even remember what it was). I could probably find out which one it is and what kind of patch it was with some websearching.  Could I Maybe log in with a new resource that automatically changes, per re-login and count the priority up in each step so messages get still delivered? It kinda feels wrong.

Comment: I would not change the resource on the same device because of this. In fact, the job of the resource is to identify the same endpoint within XMPP. All you have to do is to configure the XMPP server so that a old connection gets terminated when a new connection with the same resource is established.

Comment: HI, I have involved with such problem. Do you got solution? please help me please . Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

## Deadlock during Smack disconnect

As Airsource Ltd. mentioned in his comment: Smack is suffering from an deadlock in `disconnect()` which is loged as [SMACK-278](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-278). I have m[ade a commit that fixes this in my smack fork](https://github.com/Flowdalic/smack/commit/89d7b5b99b9a5978a4d1ac99c0de00682c4a7fcc).

## Android reconnection handling

For the network fallover, have a look at the [GTalkSMS receiver](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/gtalksms/receivers/NetworkConnectivityReceiver.java). It will issue a ACTION_NETWORK_CHANGED intent, with the boolean extras "available" and "fallover". Your service should "stop" the connection when "available=false" and "fallover=false". How you "stop" the connection is up to you. Sometimes the disconnect() takes very long even with the fix for SMACK-278, this is why we do the [disconnect in an thread that will abort after x seconds](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/gtalksms/XmppManager.java#313) and then creates a new Connection instance. We reconnect then when the intent with "available=true" is received.

You will find other examples in the GTalkSMS source. I have the app permanently running and it achieves a stable, but not 100% available connection (because of WLAN <-> GSM switches).

Comment: Than you very much, I learned a lot from that source code. I'm not quite sure whether I got the reconnect Problem figured out yet, but I'm on it right now. I guess I should walk around with the app running for a while to see what it does....

Comment: The long-running disconnect seems to be due to deadlock between the BufferedReader.close() in disconnect, and the BufferedReader.read() in PacketReader. There's a patch for this - see http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-278